# Index Types in Elasticsearch, Performance Reasons

Tags: performance, types, indexing, elasticsearch

I know what types are and for what they serve, but there are still some things which are not clear for me.

- Do types only have the function to distinguish between different mappings within the index?

OR

- Does is have an advantage in performance, if I only query a certain type of an index with multiple types. So does Elasticsearch use a quick filter to distinguish the types?
- Does Elasticsearch store documents of the same type in the same shard, if multiple shards are specified and it's therefore faster or is this only possible with explicit routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query performance depends on your data. Consider a 5 shard index. If you have 2 indices, that's 10 shards to search across vs 5 if you have two types within a single index. Depending on the amount of data overall in your system, this can have an effect on your query response time.

ES does not store all documents with the same type in the same shard. However, ES DOES enforce that parent/child documents (where parent/child are diff types) are stored in the same shard. And having mentioned parent/child, I don't think you could have parent/child across indices, so having types will allow you to use this model.